# Writing string to text file in iOS documents directory gives no errors but doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have this code to write a string to a text file in my app's default documents directory, but nothing is printed in my console, and no file gets created. What am I missing here?

```
        func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return paths[0]
        }
        
        struct ContentView: View {
            func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
                let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                print(paths)
                return paths[0]
            }
            
            var body: some View {
                Text(" Text that is written to file")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let str = "This is a test message"
                        let url = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("ARData.txt")
                        do{
                            try str.write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                            let input = try String(contentsOf: url)
                            print(input)
                        } catch{
                            print(url)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a good look at getDocumentsDirectory().  Check the data type inside it.

Comment: The code is correct and is supposed to work. But it does not show anything if it's executed in the preview canvas. You have to run it in the Simulator. @RB's There is no need to create the file explicitly.

Comment: @vadian thanks :), i just forgot thats not directory it's file it will generate by appending path.

Comment: @vadian I have it running on my iPhone, so it shouldn't be a simulator problem. Maybe I'm not looking in the right directory for the file?

Comment: As I said the code is valid (looks like from Hacking with Swift). Does it show anything?

Comment: @vadian nope, still nothing. I have it set so that my documents folder syncs to my Files app, and the app's folder exists, but it's empty and my XCode console is empty as well.